# laravel Requested Ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

in simple of my form i want to use ajax with `$.post` and get and post request with that, after using `$.post` and submit form my page is refresh and alert do not work validation of controller.

simply request ajax in controller does not working correctly

my form :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        name         = $('#name').val();
        family       = $('#family').val();
        email        = $('#email').val();
        currPassword = $('#currPassword').val();
        password     = $('#password').val();
        password_confirmation = $('#password_confirmation').val();

        $.post('{{ URL::route('admin.profile.update') }}' ,
            { 
              name                  : name,
              family                : family,
              email                 : email,
              currPassword          : currPassword,
              password              : password,
              password_confirmation : password_confirmation 
             },
             function(data){
                if(data.errors)
                    alert(data.errors)
            }
        );
        //return false; 
    });

})
</script>

 {{ Form::model($profile, array('route' => array('admin.profile.update', $profile->id), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}

                <div style='padding:10px;font-weight: bold;'>ویرایش مشخصات شخصی</div>
                <table style='width:95%;border:none;font-size:11px;margin: 5px;text-align: left'>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="80px">{{ Form::label('name' , 'نام: ') }}</td>
                        <td>{{ Form::text('name',null , array('id'=>'name', 'class' => 'form-control' )) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ Form::label('family' , 'نام خانوادگی: ') }} </td>
                        <td>{{ Form::text('family', null, array('id'=>'family', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ Form::label('email' , 'ایمیل: ') }}</td>
                        <td>{{ Form::text('email', null, array('id'=>'email', 'class' => 'form-control ltr')) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ Form::label('currPassword' , 'رمز عبور فعلی: ') }}</td>
                        <td>{{ Form::password('currPassword', array('id'=>'currPassword', 'class' =>'form-control ltr')) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ Form::label('password' , 'رمز عبور: ') }}</td>
                        <td>{{ Form::password('password', array('id'=>'password', 'class' =>'form-control ltr')) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ Form::label('password_confirmation' , 'رمز عبور مجدد: ') }}</td>
                        <td>{{ Form::password('password_confirmation', array('id'=>'password_confirmation', 'class' =>'form-control ltr')) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">{{ Form::submit('ویرایش مشخصات', array('id'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-default' , 'style'=>'float:left')) }}</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                {{ Form::close() }}
```

my Controller :

```
public function update($id)
    {
        if ( Request::ajax() ){

            $rules = array(
                'name'        => 'required|alpha',
                'family'      => 'required',
                'email'       => 'required|email',
                'currPassword'=> 'required',
                'password'    => 'required|confirmed|min:4',
                'password_confirmation'=>'required',
            );

            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                /*
                return Redirect::to('/admin/profile')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
             */
             return Response::json(array(
                    'errors'=>$validator
                ));
            }
}
}
```

My Route:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
  Route::resource  ('admin/profile' , 'ProfileController', array('as'=>'profile' , 'before'=>'csrf'));

});
```

Comment: Dou you reach the action ? You have got a filter on route.. try to disable it

Comment: @VitKos  witch filter???

Comment: No, the auth filter and csrf.

Comment: what errors are you getting.  Also, as Vit Kos asks above, does it reach your route?

Comment: @warspite page is refreshing and `$.post` and `Request::ajax` does not working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the form is submitting because you are not using `preventDefault()` but I see that you were struggling with getting that to work correctly in a previous question.  That is why your page is refreshing.

What you can do is instead of using `Form::submit()`, you can use `Form::button()` which will keep the form from submitting allowing you to do as you please with javascript.  Then, instead of using `$('form').submit()` which should no longer work because it's not submitting, attach the handler to the click event of the button.  `$('#submit').on('click', function() { // Code goes here});`

This unfortunately comes with the negative side-effect of your form not being able to function at all if the user does not have javascript enabled in the browser.

Also, depending on which browser you are using, you should be looking at the XHR requests as they happen using the developer tools, to see if there are any errors or statuses returned.